# how to add parameterized string to a query with regex

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a `JSON` column that might contain the string `"attribute":"my_value"` (among other `JSON` properties), this is the query I have to search for it:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE JSON_COLUMN REGEXP '"attribute":"?"'
```

The `execQuery` function adds an apostrophe to the parametrized string and this is the query that runs:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE JSON_COLUMN REGEXP '"attribute":"'my_value'"'
```

This is not a valid SQL query, how can I search for this parameter to get the rows that match this value?

I am using [orm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm) for `mysql` (5.6) in `nodejs`, this is how I use it:

```
execQuery(MY_QUERY, [param1], (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject({
                    error: 'cannotFetch',
                    message: err
                });
            } else {
                return resolve(data);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following query instead:

```
const MY_QUERY = `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE JSON_COLUMN REGEXP ?`;
```

And took care of the dynamic value in the `nodejs` part :

```
const getAttributeUsageTemplate = value => (`"attribute":"${value}"`);

execQuery(MY_QUERY, [getAttributeUsageTemplate(param1)], (err, data) => {
})
```

this is the only solution i found for my version of `mysql` 
the driver still surrounds the parameter with apostrophes but they don't get in the way of the regular expression

Answer (score 2):

If you have a JSON column, why wouldn't you just extract the value?

```
WHERE JSON_COLUMN->'$.attribute' = 'myvalue'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) to use JSON column in where clause

```
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_COLUMN, "$.attribute") = 'myvalue'
```

### edit:

if you use mysql 5.6 or less you must use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html)

```
WHERE  `JSON_COLUMN` REGEXP  '"attribute":[^}]*"my_value"[^}]*}'
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bW2HFSfEh4DQJGNqL8n8pX/2)

Comment: i checked my mysql version and i have 5.6.34 so it seem i cannot use that

Comment: my problem is that the parametized string is being sent with apostrophes 
so it sends '"attribute":[^}]*" 'my_value' "[^}]*}' , do you know if there is there any way to remove it?

Comment: @Anna24 you must use backslash before quote (\')

Comment: it does make the query valid ,however now it won't match the regex query [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bW2HFSfEh4DQJGNqL8n8pX/3]  
i think i will send the parameter the whole regex string instead of trying to use it only on the value , perhaps there is no neat way of doing that in versions before 5.7  
thanks for your help

Comment: @Anna24 In the fiddle you sent, the table contents there is no quotes you entered in the query quotes, see [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bW2HFSfEh4DQJGNqL8n8pX/4)

Comment: just to clarify - in the database there are no quotes on the value. The quotes in the query are not added by me they are added by the orm execQuery function to each string parameter, and i cannot control that.This is my original problem in the question, i ended up using a different query because of that